# Redirecionamento temporario

Tags: apache, htaccess

tenho uma aplicação que preciso mudar de domínio

```
app.com.br
```

preciso mudar para

```
app2.com.br
```

porem enquanto eu não altero os dns preciso de um redirecionamento temporário

preciso que quando alguém entre em qualquer path do app.com.br eu direcione para o mesmo mas no segundo domínio

por exemplo

```
app.com.br/path/teste -> app2.com.br/path/teste
```

eu consigo fazer colocando um header no index.php mas, caso alguem entre diretamente em um path sem passar pelo index php ela não é redirecionada.

como posso solucionar isso?

Answer (score 1):

O `.htaccess` deve estar na raíz do seu domínio `app.com.br` :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#Para todos os requestes para www.app.com.br
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.app\.com\.br$
#Redireciona para app2.com.br
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.app2.com.br/$1 [R=301,L]
```